# How to add my Data Drive to the Nautilus sidebar

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, places

Almost all my data is stored on my Data Drive (/dev/sda1)
I moved my Documents and Music folders and so on to this drive.
Now I want to add it to the Nautilus (1:3.26.4-0) sidebar in Ubuntu 18.04.

It doesn't need to mount somewhere else. The custom paths to folders like Documents in the sidebar are working fine.

I just want a nice button to click on to take me directly to my data drive so I don't have to bother with going through Other Locations - Data anymore.
Since it's not a folder I can't just drag and drop it to bookmark it.

Comment: You can change mount to directly mount in /home or if mounted in / or /mnt add links to add folders to /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the directory in the file manager. Use the 3 dots menu and select to bookmark. The icon looks like it does in most browser apps. 
The Ubuntu page is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-bookmarks-edit.html.en)